# Lebab cannot convert if there are fields

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, prototype, ecmascript-5, es6-class

I'm trying to convert `es5` to `es6` using [lebab](https://github.com/lebab/lebab).

`lebab es5.js -o es6.js --transform class`

if I convert simple code everything is fine. For example:

```
var className = function(values) { this.__values = values; };
className.func = function() { return "test"; };
className.func2 = function() { return "test2"; };
className.prototype = {
    _values: null,  
    put: function() { return 0; },
    get_length: function() { return this._values.length; }
};
```

To

```
class com_cie_json_JsonArray {
    constructor(values) {
        this._values = values;
    }

    static func1() {
        return "test1";
    }

    static func2() {
        return "test2";
    }

    put() {
        return 0;
    }

    get_length() {
        return this._values.length;
    }
}
```

But if I insert more fields then the `Lebab` either partially or not translates these pieces at all. This example not translated code.

```
var className = function(values) {
    this.__values = values;
};
className.func = function() {
    return "test";
};
className.func2 = function() {
    return "test2";
};
$classes[2] = $classes["name.to.className"] = className;
className.__name__ = ["name","to","className"];
className.prototype = {
    _values: null,  
    put: function(value) {
        return 0;
    },
    get_length: function() {
        return this._values.length;
    },
    __class__: className,
    __properties__: {get_length:"get_length"}
};
```

The question is how this type of code will look in ec6. And if it’s possible how to tell the `Lebab` to convert it.

```
var className = function() {
};

$classes[2] = $classes["name.to.className"] = className;
className.__name__ = ["name","to","className"];

className.prototype = {
        _values: null,  
        __class__: className,
        __properties__: {get_length:"get_length"}
};

$classes[2] = $classes["name.to.className"] = className;
className.__name__ = ["name","to","className"];
```

Comment: One thing I'd try is not putting that `$classes[2] =` statement between the constructor declaration and the prototype / static property assignment. Maybe the class-recognition heuristic bails out on that.

Comment: This sounds more like a support question suited for the project's issue tracker, possibly even a feature request/bug report, than a question that'll likely get an answer on StackOverflow.

Comment: @Bergi Yes, if I remove this line that `lebab` will do more, but I have many auto-generated classes with similar lines.

Comment: If they are auto-generated anyway, can't you just fix the generator?

Comment: @Bergi Unfortunately this impossible generator is lost :)